# I just bought a Wii U directly from Nintendo, but I cannot enter it

Tags: wii-u

So I recently bought a Wii U, but there is an account - assumingly used to test - on it, with a Parental Controls PIN assigned to the Wii U. It also had a disc inside.

I can't reset it, as there are preinstalled games.

I don't know if there are any ways to get past the PIN, or reset the PIN, so that is my question. How do I get past the Parental Controls PIN - or remove the PIN - on a Wii U?

Any advice is appreciated, apart from calling Nintendo. We've tried, and they aren't helping whatsoever...

Answer (score 1):

There is a website that you can use to remove the PIN.
https://mkey.salthax.org/
Select the Device Type, date, and inquiry number. To get the inquiry number, try to go into parental controls and click I Forgot. When it asks for the security question, click I Forgot (if it is there) or Back. It will give you an inquiry number.

In case this website goes down, the source is at https://github.com/Dazzozo/mkey.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather the only ways of getting past the PIN screen is:

1. Talking to whomever you bought it from
2. Getting in touch with Nintendo
3. Guessing the PIN, like @pinckerman says

https://www.reddit.com/r/wiiu/comments/2g7d5o/need_help_getting_into_my_wii_u_that_i_bought/